# How to get the parent entity title inside image.html.twig

Tags: theming

I want to get the node title inside an image.html.twig override so I can use it to replace the 'title' and 'alt' attributes of the image.
So far I was able to pass simple variables with THEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) but no luck getting the title of the parent node.

Comment: Try https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.5.x `template_preprocess_field()`, then check for the field name/type/etc. inside an `if ()` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution that I could find is to get `node` object in `image-formatter.html.twig` which is a wrapper to `image.html.twig`.

Add `THEMENAME_preprocess_image_formatter` to your `THEMENAME.theme`

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables) {
  $variables["node"] = $variables['item']->getEntity();
}
```

Copy `core/themes/classy/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig` into your `THEMENAME/templates` directory.

Now you can get the node title in this twig file using `{{node.getTitle()}}` or `{{node.label()}}`

The twig file might look like this

```
Node title: {{node.getTitle()}}

{% if url %}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ image }}</a>
{% else %}
  {{ image }}
{% endif %}
```

Don't forget to rebuild cache (clear cache) for the changed hooks/twig files to be seen by your Drupal installation.

**Alternatively** if you want to just change the `alt` and `title` attributes of your image based on the node title here is one way to do it (covers question in the comments)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['item']->getEntity();
  $variables["image"]["#alt"] = $node->label();
  $variables["image"]["#title"] = $node->label();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution worked as you said and I was able to print the title of the node inside image-formater.html.twig.
The problem is that I need the title inside {{ image }} so I can replace the 'title' and 'alt' attributes and I think the corresponding template is the image.html.twig but when I tried to do that by replacing:

Comment: THEMENAME_preprocess_image_formatter()
with:
THEMENAME_preprocess_image()
I get 
Error: Call to a member function getEntity() on null

Am I missing something. Is the image.html.twig the template I need or there is a way to override {{ image }} inside image-formater.html.twig?

Comment: yes entity is not available inside `THEMENAME_preprocess_image`, I am not sure why.  As a workaround you can bring all the code you have in `image.html.twig` inside  `image-formatter.html.twig`  and put it where right now there is `{{ image }}`.

Comment: If you implement the workaround just make sure other image fields don't break.

Comment: @NikosKakos also look at alternative solution in my answer based on your comment question.